# Импорт своего сертификата в хранилице сертификатов Windows

Tags: c, сертификат

Я сгенерировал сертификат и получил на выходе файл `.crt` . Мне надо его добавить в хранилице сертификатов Windows что бы на моих компьютерах. Реализовать надо это средствами языка Си. Вот я начал рыть в сторону `wincrypt.h` и функции `CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore()`, но так и не нашел работающего примера кода, если кто нибудь бы предоставил был бы признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Открыть корневое хранилище сертификатов:

```
HCERTSTORE hRootCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL,"ROOT");
```

Добавить сертификат при помощи функции [CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376015(VS.85).aspx):

```
CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore(
    hRootCertStore,
    X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
    pCertData,  // указатель на буфер, с сертификатом 
    cbCertData, // размер буфера
    CERT_STORE_ADD_USE_EXISTING,
    NULL
);
```

Закрыть хранилище:

```
CertCloseStore(hRootCertStore,0);
```

Если этот код будет выполнен из под пользователя, то сертификат будет добавлен в пользовательское корневое хранилище. Кроме того, пользователю будет показано предупреждение, где он должен будет согласиться с добавлением сертификата. Если же этот код будет выполнен из под системного аккаунта, то сертификат будет добавлен для всех пользователей и без всяких предупреждений и вопросов.

---

Перевод ответа с enSO: [Installing Root CA Cert via code on Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656735/6219657)

**Upd:**

Импортируемый сертификат должен быть в бинарном DER формате. Если ваш файл в текстовом формате, то вам нужно его конвертировать. Например, вот так:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -outform der -out cert.der
```

Comment: Вот, да. pCertData,  // указатель на буфер, с сертификатом cbCertData, // размер буфера. Вопрос по этим двум указателям. Толи там должен быть сам сертификат и его длина, либо там должен быть байтовый вариант этого сертификата...я чет пробовал и так и так но толку не получил

Comment: Вот я на скорую руку сделал. Но что-то не так как я понял ибо он не работает :DD  `char *crt = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDXTC(тут оставшаяся часть сертификата, ибо не влезло)K5 Xg== -----END CERTIFICATE-----";
    HCERTSTORE hRootCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL,"ROOT");

    printf("%d\n", CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore( hRootCertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, crt, strlen(crt), CERT_STORE_ADD_USE_EXISTING, NULL ));
    CertCloseStore(hRootCertStore,0);`

Comment: @Corle Похоже, что эта функция воспринимает только сертификаты в `DER` формате, а у вас в `Base64`. Формат сертификата можно конвертировать при помощи OpenSSL или вручную, через импорт/экспорт в InternetExplorer ([вот тут подробно всё описано](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=5531)). А если у вас возникает необходимость запостить кусок кода, пользуйтесь http://pastebin.com/